# HTML, Tables damaged

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I was about to submit my project, but i get all my tables output merged into each other...
I didn't do anything, I just saved and copied files to extra location just as backup. This is the issue from one of the pages: [cart page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NjSp.png)

Here is the CSS:

```
/* my style sheet */
body {
    font-family:verdana;
}

body {
    width:100%;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration:none; color:red;
}

h1 {
    color:blue; text-align:center;
}

h3 {
    color:Blue;
    text-align:center;
}

p {
    font-size;10pt;
    text-align:center;
}

header {
    width:75%; 
    padding:10px; 
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    border:solid;
    background-color:#8F9779;
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

nav {
    width:75%; 
    padding:10px; 
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    border:solid;
    background-color:#8F9779;
    opacity:0.9;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

main {
    width:75%; 
    padding:10px; 
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    border:solid;
    background-color:#8F9779;
    opacity:0.9;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

footer {
    width:75%; 
    padding:10px;   
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    border:solid;
    background-color:#8F9779;
    opacity:0.9;
    filter:alpha(opacity=90); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

table {
    margin-left:auto;
} 

table,th,td {
    border:solid 1px;   
}

table.table-style-one {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 400px;
    word-break: break-all;
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #3A3A3A;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.table-style-one th {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #3A3A3A;
    background-color: #B3B3B3;
}

table.table-style-one td {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #3A3A3A;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

body {
    background: no-repeat fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    width: 110px;
    font-weight: bold;
    /* color: #3B444B;
    3B444B background-color: #8F9779;*/
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    target-name:new;
    target-new:tab;
}

/*
a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #F0FFFF;
}*/

#category ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#category a {
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

#category a:hover {
    background-color:  #F0FFFF;
}

#category li {
    display: inline;
}

.wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* For IE, the outcast */
    zoom:1;
    *display: inline;
}

.wrapper li {
    float: left;
    padding: 2px 5px;
}
```

**cart.php**

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}  //start session

if (!isset($_SESSION['client_ID'])) {
    //echo "<script>alert('not logged in');</script>";
    header("Location: index.html"  );
}
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="Games, Gaming, PS4, PS3, XBOX, Video games">
<meta name="description" content="Games 4 You">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Games 4 You</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/ProductsStyle.css">
    <!-- javascript/jQuery -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--Add the following script at the bottom of the web page (before </body></html>)-->
<script type="text/javascript" async="async" defer="defer" data-cfasync="false" src="https://mylivechat.com/chatinline.aspx?hccid=42206151"></script>
<!-- Header tags above-->
<!-- Start with body tags -->
<script>// disable zoom to keep image fit and always in position
    document.firstElementChild.style.zoom = "reset";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // declare list of backgrounds
    var images = ['bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg', 'bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg'];

    // declare function that changes the background
    function setRandomBackground() {
        // choose random background
        var randomBackground = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

        // set background with jQuery
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url("Images/' + randomBackground + '")');
    }

    // declare function that sets the initial background, and starts the loop.
    function startLoop() {
        // Set initial background.
        setRandomBackground();

        // Tell browser to execute the setRandomBackground every 5 seconds.
        setInterval(setRandomBackground, 5 * 1000);
    }

    // One the page has finished loading, execute the startLoop function
    $(document).ready(startLoop);

</script>
<header id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <center><img src="Images/Title.png" alt="Title">
    </div>
        </center>
</header>
<center>
    <nav>
<?php
echo "<p> Welcome ".$_SESSION['client_name']."</p>";
//create connection
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "student", "student", "cib4003_h00233671_at");

if ($con->connect_errno) { //failed
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " . $con->connect_error;
}?>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul id="category" >
                <li><a href="Products.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="Products.php">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="Productscart.php">View Cart</a></li>
                <li><a href="ViewOrderHistory.php">Orders</a></li>
                <li><a href="Settings.php">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php">Logoff</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</center>
<main><!-- start with main tags which will include the php and tables -->
    <h3>Games Cart</h3><!-- text above the table using style to move it  -->
<?php
//new connection
$con = new mysqli("localhost", "student", "student", "cib4003_h00233671_at");
if ($con->connect_errno) { //failed
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $con->connect_errno . ") " . $con->connect_error;
}
//success 
// run sql 
$sql="SELECT * FROM products,clientscarts WHERE products.Product_Name=clientscarts.Product_Name AND clientscarts.client_ID=".$_SESSION['client_ID'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
//output 
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0) { //no records found
    echo "<p>No Orders found! what are you waiting for!? go ahead and get a game & Enjoy</p>";
?>          
    <center><img src="Images/Happy Gaming.png" alt="Order"></center>
<?php
}
else { // records were found in DB
    // echo "<p>You have: ".mysqli_num_rows($result)." pizza(s)</p>";
    // echo "<p>You have: ".$totalPizza." pizza(s)</p>";
?>

    <table class="table-style-one">
        <tr>
            <th>Order ID</th>
            <th>Product Image</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Product Type</th>
            <th>Price ($)</th>
            <th>quantity</th>
            <th>     </th>
        </tr>
        <?php 
    while ($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Order_ID']."</td>";
        echo "<td><img src='".$row['picture']."' width=199 height=188 />";
        echo "<td>".$row['Product_Name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Description']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Product_Type']."</td>";
        if ($_SESSION['User_Type'] == "VIP" && $row['Discount_VIP'] < 1 ){
            echo "<td>".($row['Price'] * $row['Discount_VIP'] )."$<h4 style=font-size:3> After Discount</h1></td>";
        }
        else if ($_SESSION['User_Type'] == "Silver" && $row['Discount_Silver'] < 1 ) {
            echo "<td>".($row['Price'] * $row['Discount_Silver'] )."$<h4 style=font-size:3> After Discount</h1></td>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<td>".$row['Price']."$ </td>";
        }

        echo "<td><center><a href='increasequantity.php?PID=".$row['Order_ID']."'/><h4>Increase &#10133</h4></a>".$row['quantity']."<a href='decreasequantity.php?PID=".$row['Order_ID']."'/><h4>Decrease &#x2796</h4></a></center></td>";
        echo "<td> <a href='removeorder.php?PID=".$row['Order_ID']."'/>Remove from cart </a></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        if ($_SESSION['User_Type'] == "VIP" && $row['Discount_VIP'] < 1 ) {
            $total=$total+($row['Price'] * $row['Discount_VIP']);
        }
        else if ($_SESSION['User_Type'] == "Silver" && $row['Discount_Silver'] < 1 ) {
            $total=$total+($row['Price'] * $row['Discount_Silver']);
        }
        else {
            $total=$total+($row['Price']*$row['quantity']);
        }

        $totalGames=$totalGames+($row['quantity']);
    }

    echo "<tr><td>Total Games:</td><td>".$totalGames." Game's</td>";
    echo "<td> <a href='removeallorder.php'/>Remove All Items</a></td>";
    echo "<td ><center>Total bill: ".$total."$ </center></td>";
    echo "<td colspan='4'><a href='Billpage.php?total='".$total."'>   <img width=200 height=96 src=Images/buy-now.png></a></td>";
    echo "</table> ";
}
?></h2>
    </main>
</body>
<!-- main tag closed followed by closing body tag -->
<footer><!-- footer start here with in-line style plus using underline for website link HCT Portal -->
    <div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL, multilanguagePage: true}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</footer><!-- Close footer -->
</html><!-- close HTML tag -->
```

Comment: It's probably in your CSS if you are making a table or table cells not act like tables and table cells. A couple comments, 1) You don't need multiple connections in your page (`$con = new mysqli("localhost", "student", "student", "cib4003_h00233671_at");`). Just one should suffice. 2) After `header("Location: index.html"  );` you need `exit;` 3) Try to be consistent with your `if/else`. This: `if (!isset($_SESSION)) {session_start();}` is inconsistent. 3a) You indentation needs to be more consistent overall.

Comment: maybe your width is to small

Comment: try <code>overflow: auto</code> it will help see the problem if half of the cards and there is a scroll bar at the bottom then you know it is the width problem

Comment: i tested all but the one that worked was editing css, in table i had the following   table-layout: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  word-break: break-all; which was the caused of this issue, i added that code before but never caused any issue.

Comment: @MrDaisy That might be because the last time you changed it, the css file was cached by your browser. This makes it so that changes don't show immediately unless you clear your browser's cache or hold shift and refresh the page.